# How to go:generate stringer constants from multiple packages?

Tags: go, generate

I have a struct like this:

```
.foo/bar/constants.go
.foo/constants.go
.main.go
```

In `main.go` I declare the type:

```
package agepack
type EventType uint
//go:generate stringer -type EventType
const (
    FirstType EventType iota
    SecondType
    ....
)
```

In each `constants.go` I have soimething like this:

```
package foo
const (
   OneMoreType agepack.EventType = 100 + iota
)
```

How can I generate stringer with values from all packages?

Comment: `stringer` generates String method and when i try to generate it to the same type in separated packages it don't work 'cause can't create new method String(and didn't update old)

Comment: You're right, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) doesn't support this. Quoting from its doc:

> With no arguments, it processes the package in the current directory. Otherwise, the arguments must name a single directory holding a Go package or a set of Go source files that represent a single Go package.

Easiest solution would be to put all enum values in the same package. You may use separate files, but they must be in the same package.

If you want / must use multiple packages, you can only do this with `stringer` if you use different types, each defined in the package in which you list the constants.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact possible to generate the Stringer interface on multiple packages: more specifically on **all** packages contained in a directory (recursively). Just use

```
$ go generate ./...
```

This is just like `go test ./...` which allows you to execute all tests contained in a directory recursively.